# Mapping factors to colors in heatmap.2

Tags: r, heatmap

Hello I am making a heatmap in R using `heatmap.2`. I would like to use the RowSideColors option. However, I can't figure out how to easily create the vector of colors for the rows.
The rows represent bacteria, and I have a dataframe with information on the bacteria that I would like to use for coloring. I will either use `Bact_Phylo_Info$Phylum` or k to create the color vector.

```
> str(Bact_Phylo_Info)
'data.frame':   33 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Phylum: Factor w/ 7 levels "Actinobacteria",..: 4 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 5 5 ...
 $ Order : Factor w/ 10 levels "Bacteroidales",..: NA 4 4 1 1 1 1 1 NA 5 ...
 $ Family: Factor w/ 13 levels "Anaplasmataceae",..: NA 4 4 NA 11 2 11 12 NA NA ...
```

I have tried a few things, for example the crazy loop below, but I think there must be an easy way that I am missing. Any help appreciated.

```
BactPhyColors <- sapply(Bact_Phylo_Info$Phylum,
    if (Bact_Phylo_Info$Phylum == levels(Bact_Phylo_Info$Phylum)[i]),
        rainbow(length(levels(Bact_Phylo_Info$Phylum)))[i]
}
)
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understood well what you tried to do: you have a variable coded as a  factor and you try to transform it to colors?
 Are creating some  discrete scale color?

Here I am using `brewer_pal` from `scales` package to create to create a brewer palette. then merge it with the factor variable.

```
library(scales)
dat <- data.frame(Phylum = gl(7,2))
n <- nlevels(dat$Phylum)
dat.col <- data.frame(Phylum =unique(dat$Phylum),
            BactPhyColors =brewer_pal()(n))  ## you can also use rainbow(n)

merge(dat,dat.col)

merge(dat,dat.col)
   Phylum     BactPhyColors
1       1 #EFF3FF
2       1 #EFF3FF
3       2 #C6DBEF
4       2 #C6DBEF
5       3 #9ECAE1
6       3 #9ECAE1
7       4 #6BAED6
8       4 #6BAED6
9       5 #4292C6
10      5 #4292C6
11      6 #2171B5
12      6 #2171B5
13      7 #084594
14      7 #084594
```